# Cannot merge an entity that has been removed

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I encountered something really puzzling in my development work.

```
removePreviousFoodMenuItems(oldRefList);
shFood.setNewFoodMenuItems(newRefList);
em.merge(shFood);
em.flush(); //Error occurs
```

If I call removePreviousFoodMenuItems before merge, I will get a "Cannot merge an entity that has already been removed" exception at runtime. However, this should not occur because I have set shFood to reference a new set of food menu items (newRefList). So why is merge still trying to merge the oldRefList elements that have already been removed? This problem does not occur if I put removePreviousFoodMenuItems after the flush statement.

```
shFood.setNewFoodMenuItems(newRefList);
em.merge(shFood);
em.flush(); //Error does not occur
removePreviousFoodMenuItems(oldRefList);
```

Below is the code for the removePreviousFoodMenuItems

```
public void removePreviousFoodMenuItems(ArrayList<FoodMenuItem> oldRefList){

        for (Object f : oldRefList) {

            FoodMenuItem foodMenuItem = (FoodMenuItem) f;
            foodMenuItem.setStakeholderFood(null);
            foodMenuItem.setPhotoEntity(null);

            em.remove(foodMenuItem);
            //em.flush();
        }//end for

    }//end removePreviousFoodMenuItems
```

Would really appreciate some advice on this!

UPDATE: How the newRefList is created:

```
StakeholderFood stakeholder = em.find(StakeholderFood.class, stakeholderID);
ArrayList<FoodMenuItem> newRefList = new ArrayList<FoodMenuItem>();

for (Object o : menuItem) {
            FoodMenuItem fmi = (FoodMenuItem) o;
            FoodMenuItem newFmi = new FoodMenuItem();
            String previousName = fmi.getItemName();

            newFmi.setItemName(previousName);
            newFmi.setItemPrice(fmi.getItemPrice());
            newFmi.setPhotoEntity(fmi.getPhotoEntity());

            //Upload the photos for each item attached to menuItem
            Photo photo = fmi.getPhotoEntity();

            if(photo!=null){
                photo.setFoodmenuItem(newFmi); //set new relationship, break off with old
                em.merge(photo); //This will merge newFmi as well Fix this tomorrow
                em.flush(); //update the links immediately
            }

            if (photo != null && fmi.getContainsImage() == Boolean.FALSE) {
                uploadFoodMenuItemImages(photo);                    
                newFmi.setPhotoEntity(photo);
                newFmi.setContainsImage(Boolean.TRUE);
                newFmi.setRenderedImage(Boolean.FALSE);
                newFmi.setRenderedImageAltText(Boolean.FALSE);
            }//end photo
            else {
                newFmi.setRenderedImageAltText(Boolean.TRUE);
            }

            newFmi.setStakeholderFood(stakeholder);
            newRefList.add(newFmi);

        }//end for
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one or more same instances of `FoodMenuItem` in both `oldRefList` and `newRefList`. Applying remove to all items in `oldRefList` then causes some of the entities in `newRefList` to become removed.

Consequence is that `shFood` holds such a list where at least one `FoodMenuItem` is removed. If perform flush before removal, then on the moment when flush takes place, there is no such a problem, because `shFood` does not reference to removed instances.

Comment: Hmm, but that shouldn't occur. Because I create a new instance for every instance in the oldRefList. I have updated my code to show how I create my newRefList. Look forward to hearing from you!

Comment: Hi, Mikko! Thanks! It finally dawn on me that the culprit was the photoEntity. Both the old and new foodmenuitems (newFmi and fmi) were pointing to the same photoEntity. Because FoodMenuItem has a cascade type of ALL with photoEntity, removing the old foodmenuitem (fmi) will also remove the photoEntity as well. Since both fmi and newfmi are referencing the same photoEntity, this will produce the same problems that you just described.